# MMOD Dlib Object Detector An impossible set of object labels was detected

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, dlib

Hi I am trying to train detector for Road Signs, analogy to fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp. I have my cropped Ground truth images in a folder **stopsign_train**.

```
string stopsign_train = "/media/user/DATA/Dataset/StopSignModeling/train             
/01/";

std::vector<string> imgListTrain, imgListValidation ;
listAllFiles(imgListTrain, stopsign_train, "png");

dlib::array<array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel > > images_train ;
std::vector<std::vector<rectangle> > stop_boxes_train ;

 //filling the stop_boxes_train and images_train

    for(unsigned int ii=0; ii < imgListTrain.size(); ii++){
        string fileName = stopsign_train + imgListTrain[ii];
        dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel > tmpImg ;
        load_png(tmpImg, fileName);
        array2d<rgb_pixel> sizeImg(18, 18);
        resize_image(tmpImg, sizeImg, interpolate_nearest_neighbor());
        images_train.push_back(sizeImg);
        dlib::rectangle tmpRect(dlib::point(2, 2), dlib::point(16, 16)) ;
        std::vector<rectangle> tmpVecRect ;
        tmpVecRect.push_back(tmpRect);
        stop_boxes_train.push_back(tmpVecRect);
    }
typedef scan_fhog_pyramid<pyramid_down<6> > image_scanner_type;
image_scanner_type scanner;
// The sliding window detector will be 16 pixels wide and 16 pixels tall.
scanner.set_detection_window_size(16, 16);
// I have tried 12 by 12 as well as 14 by 14 (samller than the   
 stop_boxes_train rectangle size as well as exact also)
int C = 1;
trainer.set_c(C);
float eps = 0.01 ;
trainer.set_epsilon(eps);
object_detector<image_scanner_type> detector = trainer.train(images_train,    
stop_boxes_train);
```

Always there is an exception with similar output like below
**-------------------------------------------**

num training images: 2284

exception thrown!
An impossible set of object labels was detected. This is happening because none
of the object locations checked by the supplied image scanner is a close enough
match to one of the truth boxes. To resolve this you need to either lower the 
match_eps or adjust the settings of the image scanner so that it hits this 
truth box. Or you could adjust the offending truth rectangle so it can be 
matched by the current image scanner. Also, if you are using the 
scan_image_pyramid object then you could try using a finer image pyramid or 
adding more detection templates. E.g. if one of your existing detection 
templates has a matching width/height ratio and smaller area than the offending
rectangle then a finer image pyramid would probably help.

image index              0

match_eps:               0.5

best possible match:     0.0926276

truth rect:              [(2, 2) (16, 16)]

truth rect width/height: 1

truth rect area:         225

nearest detection template rect:              [(10, 10) (24, 24)]

nearest detection template rect width/height: 1

nearest detection template rect area:         225

Comment: Try pulling the latest code from github and seeing what happens ;)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the @DavisKing I have changed the code little bit http://codepad.org/NQwKRE81. stopsign_train is a path to train  images, stopsign_train_gt is ground truth in a format (x,y,w,h,lbl).It is still throwing an exception (exception thrown!
An impossible set of object labels was detected). but when I used     //remove_unobtainable_rectangles(trainer, images_train, stop_boxes_train); it didn't but the cout << "training results: " << test_object_detection_function(detector, images_train, stop_boxes_train) << endl; OUTWAS 1 0  0 (recall is zero). DOWNLOADED dlib-19.4.

Comment: I also want to know how to check how many samples are removed by remove_unobtainable_rectangles(trainer, images_train, stop_boxes_train); this statement as Size of images_train is same before and after.

Comment: I also like to bring notice the roi(region of interest) the dlib::rectangle size varies from 12by12 to some 128by128 .